# How to set margin on PageLayout in ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, printing, arcgis-engine

When we create a PageLayout from the A4 Landscape template and print the layout on a pinter with A4 Landscape paper we get four pages instead of one. We are using the IPage.PageToPrinterMapping = esriPageMappingTile and the reason that we get four instead of one page is that the printer by default has a margin for the A4 format. If I try to do the same procedure for a format that the printer doesn't have a margin for it prints only one page. Is there a way to create the same margin on the PageLayout?

Steps to reproduce in ArcMap:

1. File | New...
2. Choose Templates | ISO A4 Landscape
3. File | Page and Print setup...
4. Set Printer and Map to the same
   format A4 and orientation landscape [image: Page and Print Setup dialog]
5. File | Print...[image: Print dialog]
6. The Print dialog is showing four pages

Update: Tried different approaches using the [IPage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPage_Interface/001200000n88000000/) interface but can't find any API to set the margin.

1. Tried setting the [PrintableBounds](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PrintableBounds_Property/001200000npz000000/) on the page, but it seems to be readonly:

   ```
   m_hookHelper.PageLayout.Page.PrintableBounds.Envelope.PutCoords(docPaper.PrintableBounds.XMin, docPaper.PrintableBounds.YMin, docPaper.PrintableBounds.XMax, docPaper.PrintableBounds.YMax)
   ```
2. Tried setting the [Custom size](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PutCustomSize_Method/001200000nq2000000/) on the Page and it sets the size correctly, but it corp  the layout, because it doesen't set the offset:

   ```
   m_hookHelper.PageLayout.Page.PutCustomSize(docPaper.PrintableBounds.Width, docPaper.PrintableBounds.Height)
   ```
3. Tried to set the [FormID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FormID_Property/001200000npq000000/) to be esriPageFormSameAsPrinter and it workes as long as the user chooses the layouts' orientation and format on the printer. If not, it crops the layout when it is printed.

   ```
   m_hookHelper.PageLayout.Page.FormID = esriPageFormID.esriPageFormSameAsPrinter
   ```

Comment: I've sent a bugreport to ESRI on this issue.

Comment: was there any resolution from that bug report?  If so, can I suggest that you post and accept it as an Answer to get this Question off the Unanswered list.